# Where did Sirius Black acquire wand?

Tags: harry-potter

In the book *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Sirius Black does have a wand in the episode at the Shrieking Shack. But he himself tells Harry that he had no chance of chasing  the Dementors away in Azkaban without a wand. How would Sirius have acquired his wand after his escape from Azkaban?

Comment: the duplicate, doesnt actually ever mention sirius's wand, nor does it take into account his different escape, the first answer speculated that the wands may have been kept on premise, which would have allowed the death eaters to reclaim there wands, however sirius escaped as a dog. While i believe the answer is still we dont know/speculation, it  still could be addressed separately as it has multiple aspects that differ from the previously asked question.

Comment: If Sirius' wand was kept in storage at Azkaban, I don't think his dog form would have prevented him from raiding the storeroom and retrieving it.  (There are all kinds of reasons why it might have been hard to raid the storeroom *in general*, I'm just saying, Sirius retains his human intelligence in dog form, and most adult wizards retain some ability to do magic even without their wands, so *being a dog* shouldn't have made it any *harder*.)